# exchange current facebook long-lived token with new one

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a long-lived access token and when I use the below API call, I get another token. The question is if this new token a long-lived one? And can I keep exchanging current token for a new one before 60-days expiry period is over?

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_client_id}&client_secret={app_client_secret}&fb_exchange_token={current_long_lived_access_token}"

result:
{"access_token":{new_access_token},"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":4485636}

Comment: Of course you can not just exchange an extended token that is about to expire for a new one - because then it would not make much sense for Facebook to implement an expiry in the first place. You need to get a fresh short-lived token first (so user interaction required), and then you can go and exchange that for a new long-lived one.

Comment: So is there a way to get the short-lived token programmatically? Specifically in python using API calls?